# How to do Permanent Redirect in Masonite

Tags: redirect, masonite

I can redirect the user, it works but it has `302` status, how I can redirect a user and add `301` so it will be permanent redirect?

```
request.redirect('/dashboard')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the status you need as a `status` parameter:

```py
request.redirect('/dashboard', status=301)
```

If using Masonite 2.2+ you can also create a `Redirect` route:

```py
from masonite.routes import Redirect

ROUTES = [
    Redirect('/from', '/to', status=301)
]
```